# Locked UI in Nexus3 manager (Sonatype)

Tags: sonatype, nexus3

I am using Nexus3 manager for NPM packages, While fixing some issue I accidentally made ** [Nexus Authorizing Realm](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/security.html)** inactive after that UI got stuck. Settings options are not visible to admin.
Is there any way to modify Realm settings through backend or any configuration file to manual define the Realm config?